# Parsing an XML-like file in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing

I have this file which contains several `math` tags like so:

```
<Math 
   <Unique 262963>
   <BRect  1.02176" 0.09096" 1.86024" 0.40658">
   <MathFullForm `equal[therefore[char[tau]],plus[indexes[0,1,char[tau],char[c]],minus[times[indexes[
0,1,char[tau],char[s]],string[" and  "],over[times[char[d],char[omega]],times[char[
d],char[t]]]]]],over[char[tau],char[I]]]'
   > # end of MathFullForm
   <MathLineBreak  138.88883">
   <MathOrigin  1.95188" 0.32125">
   <MathAlignment Center>
   <MathSize MathMedium>
> # end of Math
```

And like so:

```
<Math 
   <Unique 87795>
   <Separation 0>
   <ObColor `Black'>
   <RunaroundGap  0.0 pt>
   <BRect  0.01389" 0.01389" 0.17519" 0.22013">
   <MathFullForm `indexes[0,1,char[m,0,0,1,0,0],char[i]]'
> # end of MathFullForm
```

And I want to extract the contents of the `Unique` tag and the `MathFullForm` tag, but I am at a loss at how to do so. Note that `Unique` tags exist elsewhere in the file, outside of `Math` tags.

I've tried using regex but that doesn't work too well and misses many of the tags. I then thought about using an XML parser, but that wouldn't work because the code isn't valid XML.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction to do this in Python (a regex solution is acceptable).

Comment: Is your XML-like format an understood standard?   I've not come across it before.

Comment: @chocksaway It is for Adobe Framemaker: help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/mifreference/mifref.pdf

Comment: Excellent - so a standard format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop to remove the tag. `re.finditer()` can be used to iteratively extract the tags.

Check the below code and see if it works for you.

```
text = re.sub(r'\r|\n',' ',text)
for m in re.finditer(r'(\<Unique\s).*?\>',text):
   print m.group()
for m in re.finditer(r'(\<MathFullForm\s).*?\>',text):
   print m.group()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex, specifying the `DOTALL` flag(otherwise the `.` would not match the `\n` too):

```
<(Unique|MathFullForm)(.*?)>
```

The first capturing group says if the match belongs to the `Unique` or `MathFullForm` tag, whereas in the second you can find the content of the tag.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that `Unique` tags exist outside of `Math` tags as well

Comment: Why should this one be a problem for this regex?

Comment: I want the Unique number which corresponds to the MathFullForm

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by using the following regex:

```
<Math\s*<Unique[^>]*>\s*(?:<Separation[^>]*>)*\s*(?:<ObColor[^>]*>)*\s*(?:<RunaroundGap[^>]*>)*\s*<BRect[^>]*>\s*<MathFullForm `[^']*'
```

This matches the whole tag, so I can use two more regexes to extract the necessary information.